# libgdx draw texture on edges polygon

Tags: box2d, libgdx

I'm new to Libgdx, and I'm developing a small demo game such like Magic Pen (link: http://www.miniclip.com/games/magic-pen/en/ ), it uses box2d but I get stucked. I don't know how to draw crayon line on mouse touched and mouse dragged on the screen. Do they use a texture contains crayon color and make a small rectangle as a line then fill it with that texture, or they use other method ? Please anybody show me the way, i'd be appreciate for that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda did something similar before. I found a great tutorial, its action script but the ideas can be easily ported over to libgdx. It also shows how to animate your textures.

http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/create-a-glowing-flowing-lava-river-using-bezier-curves-and-shaders/

EDIT :

This link for drawing lasers using OpenGL also helped me out with the texture mapping

http://codepoke.net/2011/12/27/opengl-libgdx-laser-fx/

Comment: Great thanks to you joey.enfield :) but I'm a bit confused about all those stuffs (maybe I'm too stupid or too naive to those OpenGL things). Could you please send me a libgdx paint app demo (like paint app in windows) if you have one? thanks again bro, you have my respect

Comment: I'm afraid I dont have one. I was drawing laser beams.. the idea is similar. Have a look over the links that i've posted. They will show you how it should be done. 
The steps that I would take would be : 
1 - Get the user inputs mouse touches and just draw lines connecting the points. 
2 - Once your happy with this try and smooth the curves using the steps outlined in the tutorial. 
3 - Get practice in drawing an image in a rectangle polygon (look at mesh for libgdx examples)

Once you get this far it should be easy ;)

Comment: Thank you so much joey :D Yesterday I could finally draw rectangle polygon as a line and make many of them to form a "connecting line" drawing. Now I'm trying to texture them and I want to save them in a single "independant" texture so I can add that texture to a sprite and draw it on screen again. I heard that they use framebuffer to save stuff to a texture but I dont know exactly how to just save only what I recently draw but not all the screen (include background image and other sprites). Thank you again joey, you're my big help bro :)